# matchmedia polyfill implement

Tags: css, media-queries, polyfills

How and Why does the polyfill can work?

```
w.matchMedia = w.matchMedia || (function( doc, undefined ) {

        var bool,
            docElem = doc.documentElement,
            refNode = docElem.firstElementChild || docElem.firstChild,
            // fakeBody required for <FF4 when executed in <head>
            fakeBody = doc.createElement( "body" ),
            div = doc.createElement( "div" );

        div.id = "mq-test-1";
        div.style.cssText = "position:absolute;top:-100em";
        fakeBody.style.background = "none";
        fakeBody.appendChild(div);

        return function(q){

            div.innerHTML = "&shy;<style media=\"" + q + "\"> #mq-test-1 { width: 42px; }</style>";

            docElem.insertBefore( fakeBody, refNode );
            bool = div.offsetWidth === 42;
            docElem.removeChild( fakeBody );

            return {
                matches: bool,
                media: q
            };

        };

    }( w.document ));
```

paulirish alse implement it in another similar way, https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/blob/master/matchMedia.js

the key code is as following

```
info = ('getComputedStyle' in window) && window.getComputedStyle(style, null) || style.currentStyle;

        styleMedia = {
            matchMedium: function(media) {
                var text = '@media ' + media + '{ #matchmediajs-test { width: 1px; } }';

                // 'style.styleSheet' is used by IE <= 8 and 'style.textContent' for all other browsers
                if (style.styleSheet) {
                    style.styleSheet.cssText = text;
                } else {
                    style.textContent = text;
                }

                // Test if media query is true or false
                return info.width === '1px';
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Both work the same way.

They just inject the media that you pass as a parameter, and use it to aply a predefined style (a width of 42 px for the first, and  of 1px for the second),

If the width of the element is really the predefined one, the media is working and the function evaluates to true